# It there a way to forbid accessing ethernet interface for all processes except one?

Tags: linux, firewall, ethernet

I have two ethernet interfaces on my machine: one is for internet, and the other would be used for raw ethernet connection without tcp/ip. Also i have a program that uses this interface in promiscuous mode. However, sometimes this interface is used by linux to send broadcast telegrams. I don't know, what service exactly does this, but i need to be sure that there would be no packets on this interface except mine.

Output of `sudo ifconfig -v enp2s0`  is listed below.

```
enp2s0: flags=67<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::f137:afa0:2d44:f685  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 54:bf:64:03:a8:76  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 197  bytes 27531 (26.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

As you can see, there is 197 TX packets, althougt i did not send anything in by app. My question is how to forbid any processes except one using this interface?

Comment: Use a network sniffer like Wireshark or tcpdump to log the traffic on this interface. What unexpected traffic do you see?

Comment: Thanks for an advice. Wireshark tells that it is "ICMPv6 Multicast Listener report message", from "::" to "ff02::16". That's very weird, because i disabled both multicast and ipv6.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information, don't use comments for this purpose. How exactly did you disable IPv6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interface is configured UP and has an address.
Arrange for it to not have an inet6 address, and no more broadcast datagrams will be sent.

Comment: thanks, looks like there is no more unexpexted TX frames. However, as far as i know, this is not enought to be confident that nothing can use this interface anymore :(.

UPD: oh, seems it doesn't work. After waiting for longer time, new TX frames appeared, althought there is no inet6 line anymore in ifconfig output.

Comment: There were IP frames transmitted?!? Even though it has no IPv4 / IPv6 address?